# not able to display google map in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i am doing a sample of displaying map i have used below code but map is not getting displayed ,after displaying white screen app get closed alerting unfortunatly yourapp is closed.what mistake i have done in my coding please guide me in solving this

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.mapsample;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
       /* googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap()*/;
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission   android:name="com.example.mapsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="my_appkey" />
    </application>
```

log file

```
10-09 15:09:47.669: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
10-09 15:09:47.669: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method  11746: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted  (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
 10-09 15:09:47.669: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
 10-09 15:09:47.679: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0015 in    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.onNestedScrollAccept     ed (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
  10-09 15:09:47.679: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
 10-09 15:09:47.679: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    11752: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
 10-09 15:09:47.679: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
 10-09 15:09:47.689: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0025 in    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.onStopNestedScroll    (Landroid/view/View;)V
 10-09 15:09:47.689: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibi     lityChanged
 10-09 15:09:47.689: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method          11754: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
 10-09 15:09:47.689: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
  10-09 15:09:47.709: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,     referenced from method   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScroll Enabled
  10-09 15:09:47.709: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9397:    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
10-09 15:09:47.709: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
10-09 15:09:47.739: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.jumpDrawablesToCurrentStat     e
10-09 15:09:47.739: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    12176: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState ()V
10-09 15:09:47.739: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
10-09 15:09:47.739: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0023 in    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.jumpDrawablesToCurrentSt    ate ()V
10-09 15:09:47.759: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to find class referenced in    signature (Landroid/view/ActionMode;)
 10-09 15:09:47.849: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method     android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
 10-09 15:09:47.849: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    11749: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
 10-09 15:09:47.859: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
 10-09 15:09:47.879: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method     android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
 10-09 15:09:47.879: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    535: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
 10-09 15:09:47.879: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 10-09 15:09:47.889: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0006 in     Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintTypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations    ()I
  10-09 15:09:47.889: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method  android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method  android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
  10-09 15:09:47.889: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    557: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
 10-09 15:09:47.899: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 10-09 15:09:47.899: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0006 in    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintTypedArray;.getType (I)I
  10-09 15:09:47.969: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method   android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.setSource, referenced from method    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onInitializeAccessibilit      yEvent
 10-09 15:09:47.969: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     11859: Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;.setSource   (Landroid/view/View;)V
  10-09 15:09:47.969: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
  10-09 15:09:47.979: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.AbsActionBarView.onInitializeAccessibilityEve      nt, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onInitializeAccessibilit      yEvent
  10-09 15:09:47.979: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method   9095:    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/AbsActionBarView;.onInitializeAccessibilityE     vent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
 10-09 15:09:47.979: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x002d
 10-09 15:09:47.979: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0011-002b in    Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarContextView;.onInitializeAccessibil     ityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
 10-09 15:09:47.979: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0030-0030 in     Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarContextView;.onInitializeAccessibil      ityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
  10-09 15:09:48.089: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>, referenced from method    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
10-09 15:09:48.089: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve direct method    91: Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;I)V
  -09 15:09:48.089: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0037
 10-09 15:09:48.099: E/dalvikvm(364): Could not find class    'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
 10-09 15:09:48.099: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 41    (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in    Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
 10-09 15:09:48.099: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0029
 10-09 15:09:48.110: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x002b-0071 in   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.a   (ILandroid/content/Context;)V
 10-09 15:09:48.119: D/dalvikvm(364): DexOpt: couldn't find field    Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
 10-09 15:09:48.119: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 65
 10-09 15:09:48.119: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
 10-09 15:09:48.119: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in    Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b    (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
 10-09 15:09:48.149: I/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method    android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
  10-09 15:09:48.149: W/dalvikvm(364): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method    32: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
 10-09 15:09:48.149: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
 10-09 15:09:48.159: D/dalvikvm(364): VFY: dead code 0x0026-0030 in    Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.showErrorDialogFragment   (ILandroid/app/Activity;Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;ILandroid/content/Dialo     gInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z
 10-09 15:09:48.180: D/AndroidRuntime(364): Shutting down VM
 10-09 15:09:48.180: W/dalvikvm(364): threadid=1: thread exiting with    uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsample/com.example.mapsample.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class    fragment
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364): Caused by:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class  fragment
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at      android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarAct     ivityDelegateBase.java:228)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:1    02)
10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at    com.example.mapsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     ... 11 more
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364): Caused by:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's    AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found    0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.D(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailab      le(Unknown Source)
  10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):    at     com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.T(Unknown Source)
  10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):    at    com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.S(Unknown Source)
  10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):    at   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.nO(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:215     8)
 10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):     at    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
  10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):    at    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547      )
   10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):   at    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
   10-09 15:09:48.209: E/AndroidRuntime(364):   ... 20 more
  10-09 15:09:50.480: I/Process(364): Sen
```

Comment: attach logcat with your question

Comment: Share your LogCat error

Comment: @Syed Nazar Muhammad log file has been shared

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363337/the-meta-data-tag-in-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-have-the-right-value

Comment: @USKMobility please find log file

Comment: You have an error in your `main_activity.xml`. You didn't close `</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it happens, because map is not ready now. Try to call `mapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`, and check map in `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

Answer (score 0):

In first, you must have the following declaration within the  element in your AndroidManifest file:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" >
</meta-data>
```

Your Activity class must be looks like:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is ready!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```